# Der Fall ist hier Akkusativ? Der ganze Satz zeigt Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

Ich lerne momentan mit dem Buch [Das Ende der Megamaschine](https://docplayer.org/76312598-Fabian-scheidler-das-ende-der-megamaschine.html) Deutsch. Mit diesem Satz haben wir Akkusativ Maskulin?

> Mit der schwindenden Fähigkeit der Megamaschine, den Menschen eine Zukunftsperspektive zu bieten, **zerfällt außerdem der Glaube an ihren Mythos.**
> <sub>Fabian Scheidler: Das Ende der Megamaschine (2015 Promedia Wien)</sub>

Dankeschön

Comment: "Studieren" ist eine Aktivität, die man ausübt, wenn man an einer Universität oder Fachhochschule angemeldet ist und dort im Rahmen eines Studiums, das mehrere Semester dauert, von den dort tätigen Lehrkräften unterrichtet wird. Wenn du dir etwas autodidaktisch aneignest, heißt diese Tätigkeit "lernen". Wenn du dir also mit Hilfe eines Buches Deutschkenntnisse aneignest, dann *studierst* du nicht Deutsch. Wenn du das machst, *lernst* du Deutsch. Ich habe das irreführende Verb in deiner Frage durch ...

Comment: ...das besser passende ersetzt. Außerdem sollte man nie beim Kontext sparen. Daher habe ich das von dir gepostete Satzfragment durch den ganzen Satz ergänzt und bei dieser Gelegenheit auch gleich die Quelle angegeben. Das sollte man generell immer machen, denn dann haben wir, die wir deine Frage beantworten wollen, auch die Möglichkeit, uns noch mehr Kontext anzusehen, falls wir das für notwendig halten.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Der zitierte Satz enthält das Substantiv (substativierte Verb) "das Fallen" nicht. Daher kann es auch nicht im Akkusativ sein. Bitte spezifiere, bei welchem Substantiv im zitierten Satz der Kasus unklar ist.

Comment: Oh! Ich meinte eigentlich der Kasus bei "zerfallen"

Comment: Danke dafür der Kontext des Satzfragments zu stellen, Hubert. Das ist interessant, wie "studieren" v "lernen" verwendet werden.

Comment: @PipRosi: Vergiss bitte nicht, die Antworten zu bewerten.

Answer (score 1):

In dem Satzfragment steht "der Glaube" als Subjekt im Nominativ und "ihren Mythos" nach der Präposition "an" im Akkusativ. Beide sind Maskulinum.

Comment: Sehr hilfreich, danke!

Comment: @PipRosi wenn du mit einer Antwort zufrieden bist, gib ihr doch bitte ein Upvote (Pfeil auf der linken Seite). Das motiviert Leute auch in Zukunft Fragen zu beantworten. Schließlich kannst du noch eine "beste" Antwort auswählen, in dem du auf den Haken (auch links) klickst.

Comment: Ja, ich habe 'upvoted'! Aber es sagt, dass ich noch nicht genug points um es zu zeigen haben oder sowas?

Comment: Aber mein "feedback has been recorded"

Comment: "Your reputation score goes up when others vote up your questions, answers and edits. As you earn reputation, you'll unlock new privileges like the ability to vote, comment, and even edit other people's posts." Also ich brauche erstmal votes.

Comment: Und: ""You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 1):

Kurze Antwort:

Ein ganzer Satz steht niemals in irgend einem Fall. Nur bestimmte Teiles des Satzes stehen in bestimmten Fällen.

---

Im Detail:

Das Subjekt des Satzes ist die Nominalgruppe *»der Glaube an ihren Mythos«.* Das Verb ist das Wort *»zerfällt«.* Es steht, wie in jedem vollständigen deutschen Aussagesatz an der zweiten Position des Satzes. Die erste Position (alles von *»mit«* bis *»bieten«*) ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung, die einen ziemlich komplizierten inneren Aufbau hat: Der Kern *»Fähigkeit«* hat mehrere Attribute, eines davon ist ein Relativsatz, das ist der Teil, der zwischen den beiden Kommas steht.

Das Subjekt *»der Glaube an ihren Mythos«* ist - wie schon erwähnt - eine Nominalgruppe, und diese Gruppe steht als ganzes im Nominativ. Der Grund dafür ist, das diese Gruppe das Subjekt ist, und das Subjekt steht immer im Nominativ.

Der Kern dieser Gruppe ist das Substantiv *»Glaube«.* Links davon steht der bestimmte Artikel *»der«.* Rechts davon steht eine weitere innere Nominalgruppe: *»an ihren Mythos«.* Diese innere Nominalgruppe ist ein Attribut des Wortes *»Glaube«.* Sie gibt also Auskunft über die besondere Ausprägung des Glaubens.

Nun stehen innere attributive Nominalgruppen aber sehr häufig im Genitiv (»der Gaube *des Volkes*«; »das Haus *meines Vaters*« usw.). Das muss aber nicht immer so sein.

Das Substantiv *»Glaube«* stammt vom Verb *»glauben«* ab, und dieses Verb kann mit einem optionalen Präpositionalobjekt verwendet werden, das mit der Präposition *»an«* beginnt:

> Markus glaubt **an Gott.**
> Irene glaubt **an das Gute im Menschen.**
> Simon glaubt **an ihren Mythos.**

Die Präposition *»an«* wiederum braucht rechts von sich ein Objekt. *»An«* ist zwar eine Wechselpräposition, die ihr Objekt sowohl im Dativ (*»Schmutz klebt an **dem Glas**«*) als auch im Akkusativ haben kann, aber in Verbindung mit dem Verb *»glauben«* ist nur der Akkusativ möglich. Die Satzteile *»Gott«, »das Gute im Menschen«* und *»ihren Mythos«* sind also innere Akkusativobjekte eines Präpositionalobjekts.

Das Substantiv *»Glaube«* erbt nun die Fähigkeit, ein Präpositionalobjekt an seiner Seite zu haben, vom Verb *»glauben«.* Es kann dasselbe Präpositionalobjekt bei sich haben, und dieses Präpositionalobjekt wird dadurch zu einem Attribut (nämlich zu einem Präpositionalattribut) des Substantivs *»Glaube«.*

---

Wir haben also folgendes:

- **der Glaube an ihren Mythos**
  Das ist Subjekt des Satzes. Es ist eine Nominalgruppe, die im Nominativ steht. Diese Nominalgruppe besteht aus drei Teilen:

  - **der**
    Das ist ein Bestimmer (ein Determinativ). Determinative können mehrere verschiedene Wortarten sein, hier ist es ein bestimmter Artikel. Nachdem der Kern der Nominalgruppe ein maskulines Substantiv ist, muss auch der Artikel maskulin sein. Und weil der Kern (und damit die ganze Gruppe) im Nominativ steht, muss auch der Artikel im Nominativ stehen.
  - **Glaube**
    Das ist der Kern der Nominalgruppe. Er ist ein männliches Substantiv. Er steht im Nominativ und dadurch steht die Gruppe als Ganzes ebenfalls im Nominativ.
  - **an ihren Mythos**
    Das ist ein Attribut des Kerns der Nominalgruppe. Dieses Attribut ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Es besteht aus zwei Teilen:

    - **an**
      Das ist die Präposition, die das Präpositionalobjekt einleitet. Die Präposition *»an«* braucht hier (weil sie in einem Attribut von *Glaube* exisitert) zwingend ein Akkusativobjekt rechts von sich.
    - **ihren Mythos**
      Das ist eine Nominalgruppe, und sie ist das innere Objekt des Präpositionalobjekts. Aus den zuvor genannten Gründen muss diese Gruppe im Akkusativ stehen. Diese Gruppe besteht selbst ebenfalls aus zwei Teilen:

      - **ihren**
        Das ist der Bestimmer, der die Nominalgruppe einleitet. Bestimmer sind häufig Artikel (daher nennt man Bestimmer manchmal auch "Artikelwörter"), aber hier ist es ein Possessivpronomen. Ein Possessivpronomen gibt eine Zugehörigkeit oder ein Besitzverhältnis an. Das  Possessivpronomen hängt dabei sowohl vom Geschlecht des Besitzers als auch vom Geschlecht des Dings ab, das besessen wird (siehe unten). Hier ist der Besitzer feminin (*»die Megamaschine«*) und das besessene Ding ist maskulin  (*»der Mythos«*). Außerdem muss der Bestimmer im selben Fall wie das Substantiv stehen, das er bestimmt, und das ist hier der Akkusativ.
      - **Mythos**
        Das ist der Kern der innersten Nominalgruppe. Es handelt sich hier um ein maskulines Substantiv, das im Akkusativ steht.

---

##### Possessivpronomen

- Weiblicher Besitzer

  > Die Frau besitzt eine Gabel. Das ist **ihre** Gabel. Diese Gabel ist **ihre.** Diese Gabel ist die **ihre.**
  > Die Frau besitzt einen Löffel. Das ist **ihr** Löffel. Dieser Löffel ist **ihrer.** Dieser Löffel ist der **ihre.**
  > Die Frau besitzt ein Messer. Das ist **ihr** Messer. Dieses Messer ist **ihres.** Dieses Messer ist das **ihre.**
  > Die Frau besitzt viele Bestecke. Das sind **ihre** Bestecke. Diese Bestecke sind **ihre.** Diese Bestecke sind die **ihren.**
- Männlicher Besitzer

  > Der Mann besitzt eine Gabel. Das ist **seine** Gabel. Diese Gabel ist **seine.** Diese Gabel ist die **seine.**
  > Der Mann besitzt einen Löffel. Das ist **sein** Löffel. Dieser Löffel ist **seiner.** Dieser Löffel ist der **seine.**
  > Der Mann besitzt ein Messer. Das ist **sein** Messer. Dieses Messer ist **seines.** Dieses Messer ist das **seine.**
  > Der Mann besitzt viele Bestecke. Das sind **seine** Bestecke. Diese Bestecke sind **seine.** Diese Bestecke sind die **seinen.**
- Sächlicher Besitzer

  > Das Kind besitzt eine Gabel. Das ist **seine** Gabel. Diese Gabel ist **seine.** Diese Gabel ist die **seine.**
  > Das Kind besitzt einen Löffel. Das ist **sein** Löffel. Dieser Löffel ist **seiner.** Dieser Löffel ist der **seine.**
  > Das Kind besitzt ein Messer. Das ist **sein** Messer. Dieses Messer ist **seines.** Dieses Messer ist das **seine.**
  > Das Kind besitzt viele Bestecke. Das sind **seine** Bestecke. Diese Bestecke sind **seine.** Diese Bestecke sind die **seinen.**
- Mehrere Besitzer

  > Die Leute besitzen eine Gabel. Das ist **ihre** Gabel. Diese Gabel ist **ihre.** Diese Gabel ist die **ihre.**
  > Die Leute besitzen einen Löffel. Das ist **ihr** Löffel. Dieser Löffel ist **ihrer.** Dieser Löffel ist der **ihre.**
  > Die Leute besitzen ein Messer. Das ist **ihr** Messer. Dieses Messer ist **ihres.** Dieses Messer ist das **ihre.**
  > Die Leute besitzen viele Bestecke. Das sind **ihre** Bestecke. Diese Bestecke sind **ihre.** Diese Bestecke sind die **ihren.**

Comment: Großartig.  Ich mache gerade ausführliche Notizen.

Answer (score 1):

Oft hilft es den Satz umzustellen und zu vereinfachen:

> [Der Glaube an ihren Mythos] zerfällt.

*an etwas glauben* und *der Glaube an jemanden/etwas* brauchen beide ein Objekt im Akkusativ.

Die Grundform von Mythos lautet *der Mythos*.

> [Der Glaube]<sub>Nom.mask.</sub> an [ihren Mythos]<sub>Akk.mask.</sub> zerfällt.

Reordering the sentence does not change the cases.

Comment: Danke! Ich sehe jetzt (von Sie und Hubert), dass "zerfallen" hat nichts wirklich zu tun mit dem Akkusativ hier, nur "glauben an" entscheidet das Akkusativ. Habe ich das richtig?

Comment: @PipRosi: Korrekt. Möglicherweise verwirrend ist, dass zerfallen selbst auch den Akkusativ fordern kann, zum Beispiel: _Der Glaube an ihren Mythos zerfällt in tausend Teile_. Dies ist aber optional.